# Get all elements between elements of the same class with jquery

Tags: html, jquery, dom

I have the following element-tree in the DOM:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="separator1"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="separator2"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I also have the following structure:

```html
<div class="separator1"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="separator2"></div>
```

How do I get all elements that are between the element with class "separator1" and the element with class "separator2" in both scenarios?

In the first example I want to return all tr's that are between in the second example all divs that are between but with the same function.

What I tried were `nextAll()` and `nextUntil()` but they are only returning siblings which is working in the case of the second example but not with the first one.

Comment: Why are we not allowed to target the parents?

Comment: There are two different cases which i would like to handle global and i dont want to target the parents because in the second case there are different parents(so no tr-parents but div-parents) than in case 1.

Comment: Clarified the question by reording from "I have A, how do I do X (also for B)" to "I have A and B, how do I do X (for both)"

Comment: Short answer: you can't. You're thinking in "flat text html file", but that's now how DOM elements are arranged, they're in a tree format and in the first case there are no other elements around `separator1` *other* than the parent elements, so you have to go up the tree.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I just added a new class to the parents manually, so i can work with nextUntil().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do need to handle the parents

```js
const $from = $("tr").has(".separator1");
const $to   = $("tr").has(".separator2");
const $range = $from.nextUntil($to)
console.log($range.text())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="separator1">Sep1</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>Cell 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cell 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cell 3</td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="separator2">Sep2</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```